# API-Gateway Integration Request HTTP Header not mapping query string to header

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

On Api-Gateway i'm trying so set up mapping from 'Method Request' query string to 'integration request' headers to lambda but the mapping never reach the lambda function.

On 'Method Request' > 'URL Query String Parameters' I set it up the name 'customerIdentification'

Then as the documentation says: [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters)

went to 'Integration Request' > 'HTTP Headers' add a name 'userId' and mapped to 'method.request.querystring.customerIdentification'

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

    fmt.Printf("Processing request data for request %s.\n", request.RequestContext.RequestID)
    fmt.Printf("Body size = %d.\n", len(request.Body))

    fmt.Println("Headers:")
    for key, value := range request.Headers {
        fmt.Printf("    %s: %s\n", key, value)
    }
    xxx, err := json.Marshal(request.Headers)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("*** err *** err *** err *** err *** err ")
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("*** err *** err *** err *** err *** err ")
    }
    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: string(xxx), StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)
}
```

I expect that on the golang lambda function code I can retrieve the 'userId' from 'request.Headers'.

but it always come empty

Comment: try to check on returned error from `json.Marshal()` statement

Comment: just did again because you asked, no errors on cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a value for any key from map in golang you can simply do like this

```
val, ok := request.Headers["userId"]
if ok { // the key is present
    fmt.Println(val)
}
```

But are you sure, the key 'userId' is in header? usually these kind of keys will be in body only. If you want to cross check try to ***unmarshal your request.Body into map[string]string*** and retrieve "userd" from there.

Comment: The doubt is why aws is not passing the parameters to the GO lambda.
Before post the question I was marshalling the entire request, and the value was not present in any other field

Comment: try request type as **map[string]interface{}** in the handleRequest's param like`func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, request map[string]interface{}) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) { }` then try to marshal the whole request.

Comment: As you asked like _On 'Method Request' > 'URL Query String Parameters' I set it up the name 'customerIdentification'_. So you are expecting key in QueryParam right, if it is so _get customerIdentification_ like `request.QueryStringParameters["customerIdentification"]`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you, I think the Http Headers will only forwarded if you use http or aws service proxy as shown in this document
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html

```
For an HTTP proxy or an AWS service proxy, to associate a path parameter, a query string parameter, or a header parameter defined in the integration request with a corresponding path parameter, query string parameter, or header parameter in the method request of the HTTP proxy or AWS service proxy, do the following...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Rest API` make sure to set integration type to `AWS_PROXY`. It allows you to deal with events and gives you full control of response.

Using `CLI` :

```
$ aws apigateway put-integration --rest-api-id {rest-api-id} \
--resource-id {resource-id} --http-method ANY --type AWS_PROXY \
--integration-http-method {http-method} \
--uri {uri}
```

Using `Console` :

[image]