# AWS API Gateway integration request Http headers not being passed to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

This is similar to this post [API-Gateway Integration Request HTTP Header not mapping query string to header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57087356/api-gateway-integration-request-http-header-not-mapping-query-string-to-header) but I can't see any answer for it and all of the answers are not related to what the question is intended.

I am trying to add the integration request parameters in API Gateway, but whenever I set 'Http Headers' [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9hk.png) and 'Mapping template' as passthrough, I could not see that header when I log inside the lambda.

Also in the integration response I cannot reference it inside the integration header response parameters. The "integration.response.header.cokers" will be returned blank when I invoke the API. [This is how I configured the integration response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOYk1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately the solution here is to implement a [lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy).

A proxy integration in API Gateway tells API Gateway to simply forward all headers to the integration for processing, which means you will see all of those values in your lambda function.

NOTE: Lambda has to return a specific response format back to API Gateway if it's a proxy integration. Ultimately, the response should be something like:

```
    {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'echo-proxy': True
        },
        'body': 'some payload'
    }
```

What you are trying to do right now is map everything manually, which is a deprecated approach and usually you don't want to do that unless you absolutely have to because it's kind of a pain.

If you have to map the headers manually start by mapping them in the the method request so it can carry on to the next step and so on. Basically like this:

> Method Request -> Maps variable to Integration Request -> Maps variable to Body Mapping Template -> Maps variable to actual request header

What you have in your screenshot for the Integration Request -> HTTP Headers is:

> Name: cokers
>      Mapped from: 'blah'

However, "mapped from" should look something like "method.request.header.coker" which is a standardized path (meaning to get the value from the Method Request Header field with name "coker").

Once you have added the coker header to the Method Request, and the Integration Request HTTP Headers are mapped correctly, you have to implement a mapping template. Set the content-type to application/json with passthrough set to "When there are no templates defined(recommended)" and a simple mapping template:

```
    {
      "headers": {
        "coker" : "$input.params('coker')"
      }
    }
```

That is the way my API is setup and it returns the following to me because I had my lambda function return the event as a json object back to API GW:

```
{"body": "{\"headers\": {\"coker\": \"mapped\"}}", "statusCode": 200}
```

NOTE: the value of my header "coker" in the request on the client side is "mapped"

**UPDATED ANSWER**

To map the original "coker" header to "coker2" (or any other name you want to give it) you simply set the name of the header in your mapping template like so:

```
    {
      "headers": {
        "coker2" : "$input.params('coker')"
      }
    }
```

Then edit your lambda function to return "coker2" header and you should get a response like this:

```
{"body": "{\"headers\": {\"coker2\": \"mapped\"}}", "statusCode": 200}
```

Comment: I am using non proxy to automatically generate the documentation and json schema.
In this case means that the $input.params('coker') only came from request header 'coker' ? even if I don't set the "Integration Request HTTP Headers" it will still be available right ?
What I actually wanted is let say in "Integration Request HTTP Headers" I map coker2 with "method.request.header.coker" and in "mapping template" I map it with "$input.params('coker2')". I dont think it will be available in lambda.

Comment: @HansTjipto The "$input.params" is referring to the original variable name. So you would have to map headers with name "coker2" and the input params as 'coker'. I'll test this shortly and change up my answer a bit. I'm super curious why you would want to change the header name though? If it were me I'd leave it as coker all of the way through, because it's easier to track/diagnose later if you have any issues and want to verify it etc...

Comment: Oh, that was fast I still had the original API i tested on setup so I just changed the name in my mapping template and deployed it and it works too! Answer has been updated

Comment: Thanks, In the end that's what I did too, so it means we can't map it from "Integration Request HTTP Headers" right ? I feel that the "Integration Request HTTP Headers" is a bit useless. 
Actually, we had some changes on the headers but we don't really want to modify our lambda as it is used by other direct invocation.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that it's not meant to be "useful" to you or me, but it's just the way the application is designed and these are the steps required to get it to the lambda function. I'm still curious though, why is it important to map it specifically in the Integration Request? Seems like the end goal is achieved either way, you can reference it precisely how you want once it's made it to lambda?